# Execution order inside for loop - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a dynamic div using a for loop and I was surprised by the output. The code looks as follows:

```
for(continent in CityList)
{
  $('<div id="'+continent+'Display"><div class="row top-buffer">').appendTo('#Display');

      currentcontinent = CityList[continent];

   for(city in currentcontinent) {

   $('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><div class="caption"><h3>'+CityList[continent][city]['EngName']+'</h3><a data-name="'+city+'" href="#'+city+'"> <img src="'+CityList[continent][city]['src']+'" style="min-height:250px;height:250px;"/></a></div></div></div>').appendTo('#Display');
   }

   $('</div></div>').appendTo('#Display');
}
```

The output html using

```
alert($("div#Display").clone().html());
```

is:

```
<div id="AmericaDisplay"><div class="row top-buffer"></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div     class="thumbnail"><div class="caption"><h3>Boston</h3><a data-name="Boston" href="#Boston"> <img src="undefined" style="min-height:250px;height:250px;"></a></div></div></div>...
```

As you can see there are two `</div></div>` after the first append, but I expect those to be at the end of the html since I call them last in the for loop. Is there any reason for the loop to behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `$('<div id="Display"><div class="row top-buffer">')` will create jquery object so if you append it, the html will look like this

```
<div id="Display">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want to append the `</div></div>` in the end then save all the html in a variable and append it in the end

```
for(continent in CityList){
    var data = '<div id="'+continent+'Display"><div class="row top-buffer">';
    currentcontinent = CityList[continent];
    for(city in currentcontinent) {
        data += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><div class="caption"><h3>'+CityList[continent][city]['EngName']+'</h3><a data-name="'+city+'" href="#'+city+'"> <img  src="'+CityList[continent][city]['src']+'" style="min-height:250px;height:250px;"/></a></div></div></div>'
    }

    data += '</div></div>';
    $(data).appendTo('#Display'); // or ('#Display').append(data);
}
```

Comment: Careful of inadvertently recommending the use of global variables by omitting the `var` keyword for your `data` variable. You don't want to be creating a global `data` variable like that. It will bite you in the bum when you least expect it.

Answer (score 2):

when you parse a tag with jQuery it creates a DOM object, which includes closing tags as well. If you want `$('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail">...` to go inside `$('<div id="'+continent+'Display"><div class="row top-buffer">')` you need to append it to `'#' + continent + 'Display'` like so:

```
$('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><div class="caption"><h3>'+CityList[continent][city]['EngName']+'</h3><a data-name="'+city+'" href="#'+city+'"> <img src="'+CityList[continent][city]['src']+'" style="min-height:250px;height:250px;"/></a></div></div></div>').appendTo('#' + continent + 'Display');
```

also, get rid of `$('</div></div>').appendTo('#Display');`, it serves no purpose when parsing elements with jQuery.

Comment: To explain further: José is trying to use `.appendTo()` as a replacement for `.innerHTML += ...`, whereas it is actually adding a whole child node to the selected node(s).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I have a better understanding about what is going on now.